# Is there any relationship between the FFT and linear prediction?

Tags: fft, linear-prediction

Is there any relationship between the FFT and linear predictive methods?  Can an FFT result or the input to an FFT be modified to do non-circular prediction/extrapolation from the FFT results.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to mind is that a linear predictor can be implemented using the LMS algorithm, and the LMS algorithm can be implemented in block fashion using FFTs (see Chapter 7 of [Haykin's *Adaptive Filter Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013267145X)). I wouldn't say that implies any kind of *relationship*, but FFTs can be used to accelerate the implementation of some linear predictors.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the linear prediction problem can be thought as a filtering operation. Actually many linear predictors are based on FIR filters. So Technically you can implement the FIR filter with an FFT (And in a more efficient way depending on the size of the data).

As a Reference, try "The Theory of Linear Prediction - Vaidyanathan"

[http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Prediction-Synthesis-Lectures-Processing/dp/1598295756](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598295756)